# Can I get help with this regular expression that should only contain a maximum of two (2) consecutive, repeat characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the regular expression that I am trying to modify:

The client only wants the user to be able to enter a maximum of 2 of the same consecutive characters.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-().\&\@\?\""#,\+\''\s\/]{7,}$
```

Comment: This isn’t some password check, is it?

Comment: @Gumbo, lol, you must be a hacker or are you a cracker? hmmm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?:([a-zA-Z0-9-().&@?"#,+'\s\/])(?!\1\1)){7,}$/
```

Here the negated look-ahead assertion `(?!\1\1)` is tested for each character that is matched by `([a-zA-Z0-9-().&@?"#,+'\s\/])`. It looks at the next two following characters and tests if they are the same as the previously matched one. If this is not the case, the negated look-ahead assertion is fulfilled.

Comment: This is a javascipt RegEx why is this in double quotes?

Comment: @Amen: I did not quote anything.

Comment: So is this what the regex should look like? Because I am getting and error when I debug it. 
(?!([a-zA-Z0-9-().&@?"#,+'\s/])\1\1)

Comment: @Amen: You need to escape the `/` inside the regular expression.

Comment: Here is the expression
^(?:(?!([a-zA-Z0-9-().&@?"#,+'\s\/])\1\1)[a-zA-Z0-9-().&@?"#,+'\s\/]){7,}$

Comment: @Amen: It works for me: `/^(?:(?!([a-zA-Z0-9-().&@?"#,+'\s\/])\1\1)[a-zA-Z0-9-().&@?"#,+'\s\/]){7,}$/.test("fooobar")` returns *false*.

Comment: I am getting an error because of the single and double quotes. The " before the # sign and the ' before the \

Comment: @Amen: You don’t need to quote it when you’re using the RegExp literals `/…/` as mentioned.

Comment: I think I am getting error because this following patter appears twice in the RegExp you sent:
"#,+'

Comment: @Amen: `/`, `'` and `"` have no special meaning to a *regex*, but you have to escape whichever one you're using as a delimiter.  So it's either `/\/'"/` (regex literal) or `new RegExp('/\'"')` or `new RegExp("/'\"/")` (constructor with string literal).

Comment: The only way it works for me in JavaScript is like this 
^(?:(?!([a-zA-Z0-9-().&@?""#,+''\s\/])\1\1)[a-zA-Z0-9-().&@?""#,+''\s\/]){7,}$

Comment: @Gumbo: It would be neater to do the lookahead after, don't you think? `/^(?:([xyz])(?!\1\1)){7,}$/`

Comment: @Alan Moore: Yes, definitely.